# AirPlay Receiver option in Sharing prefs

Tags: macos, airplay, preferences

To begin, I know NOTHING about coding or programming. The last programming I ever wrote was in basic on my Commodore 64 in 1987. With that said...

Working on a Mac mini 2018. OS Monterey 12.5.1

Officially, this model Mac mini does *not* work as an AirPlay receiver. **But**, with some releases of Monterey the AirPlay Receiver option has been visible and functional in the sharing preferences pane. Over on Github I read that it was deactivated with OS 12.3, but then when I upgraded to OS 12.5 and 12.5.1 it was working again. [image]

Then, yesterday I got some strange error message about the "hash" on the startup volume having a match error. I was advised to reboot in recovery mode and re-install the OS, which I did. And now, AirPlay Receiver is gone again from the preferences pane.

[image]

It seems like there should be a simple terminal command which can toggle the AirPlay Receiver option in the preferences pane on again.

In System > Library > PreferencePanes > SharingPref > (show package contents) > Resources there are a bunch of folders, some of which which appear to be language-based preferences files (named en_AU.lproj of fr_CA.lproj, for example). There are files named AirPlayReceiverSharing.nib and AirPlayRecieverSharing.strings. Opening the later with text edit I see:

> bplist00⁄________

Y116.title\200121.titleY117.title_mIl-DC-NCa.title_bYd-eX-SH9.title_P42-oM-Rl5.title_hbk-jk-nCG.title\100115.title_MY9-qL-7iR.title\100146.title\Current user_AirPlay Receiver is On_Anyone on the same network_Multiline Label_Require passwordXEveryone_3**AirPlay Receiver is disabled by your administrator.**URadioo__∑˙_

It seems like an admin should be able to enable it. Any ideas?